# GameKit WiFi works on a simulator but not on a device

Tags: iphone, wifi, p2p, gamekit, gksession

I have faced an unexplainable problem while working with GameKit. When establishing connection over WiFi (`picker.connectionTypesMask = GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeOnline;`) devices cannot see each other. they see nothing while simulator sees everything, it can see any device or a simulator working on a different machine. i've been banging my head over it for few days already trying to understand why it works on a simulator but not on a device. Can anyone please help me?

This is how i create my session

```
 if (type == GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeOnline) 
{
    picker.delegate = nil;
    [picker dismiss];
    [picker autorelease];

    [alert setTitle:@"\n\n\n"];
    [alert setMessage:@"Looking for other iPads, iPhones or iPod touches..."];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *progress   = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(125, 50, 30, 30)];
    progress.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;
    [alert addSubview:progress];
    [progress startAnimating];
    [alert show];

    self.gameSession = [[GKSession alloc] initWithSessionID:kSessionID displayName:nil sessionMode:GKSessionModePeer];
    self.gameSession.available = YES;
    self.gameSession.delegate = self;
    self.gameSession.disconnectTimeout = 0;
    [self.gameSession setDataReceiveHandler:self withContext:nil];
}
```

Comment: did you get working. I have 3 devices. who cant search each other using wifi, but

Comment: Any update on this? I have the same problem. It only seems to be on some networks though. I have a feeling it may be related to ports used?